# Access a Node Port Service in a private GKE Cluster from another GKE private cluster

Tags: firewall, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google cloud and I have two GKE private clusters.

One of them contains some services installed as nodePort. The other cluster needs to connect to this one and access the services exposed.

The cluster with services exposed has only one node with a private IP. I can ping this node with success from the another cluster using this private IP.

But how can I access the services?

I also tried to config some firewall rules with no success.

Comment: Hi, can you please add service config and what exactly issue you are facing when trying to reach that service from another cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your situation right, than you have 2 private GKE's clusters and would like to know if it is possible to reach apps that run on one cluster from another one.

The short and general answer is **Yes, that's possible**.

Below you can see details and proofs from my testing.
I have quickly buld the following setup (both clusters are identical, except of `Master/Service/Pod address ranges`):

```
cluster-4
Cluster Master version: 1.14.10-gke.27
Total size: 1
Network: default
Subnet: default
VPC-native (alias IP): Enabled
Pod address range: 10.24.0.0/14
Service address range: 10.0.32.0/20
Private cluster: Enabled
Master address range: 172.16.1.0/28 

cluster-5

Pod address range: 10.60.0.0/14
Service address range: 10.127.0.0/20
Private cluster: Enabled
Master address range: 172.16.2.0/28
```

Firewall configuration should allow traffic from 'Pod address ranges' to Nodes. In other words traffic originated from cluster's-5 'Pod address range' shall be seliveed to the Cluster-4's node IP.

For that I have added a rule that allows tcp traffic from 10.60.0.0/14 to "all nodes in network" on port 31526.

My nginx runs on `cluster-4`

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide 
NAME            STATUS   AGE   VERSION           INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP                              
gke-cluster-4   Ready    48m   v1.14.10-gke.27   10.128.0.12                 

$ kubectl get svc -o wide 
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE     
hello-nginx  NodePort    10.0.40.183   <none>        80:31526/TCP   2m23s
```

So my nginx shall be available at `10.128.0.12:31526` for all the clients that are outside of my `cluster-4`.

I've ran  a busybox pod on `cluster-5`

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox-68dc67fcc5-gwd95   1/1     Running   0          11s
```

and tried acessing my nginx.

```
$ kubectl exec -it busybox-68dc67fcc5-gwd95 -- sh

# route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.60.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.60.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

# wget 10.128.0.12:31526
Connecting to 10.128.0.12:31526 (10.128.0.12:31526)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |************|   612  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

The `10.60.0.1` is the IP address that is assigned to `cbr0` interface on my `cluster-5` node.

```
kiwi@gke-cluster-5 ~ $ ifconfig 
cbr0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.60.0.1
```

---

Last but not least, I have checked waht's the official documentation says on topic and it appeared that it is well in line with my findings.

> [Private clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#overview) give you the ability to isolate nodes from having inbound and outbound connectivity to the public internet. This is achieved as the nodes have internal RFC 1918 IP addresses only.

Even though the node IP addresses are private, external clients can reach Services in your cluster. If we speak about NodePort type service, than it is needed creating an Ingress.

GKE uses information in the Service and the Ingress to configure an HTTP(S) load balancer. External clients can then call the external IP address of the [HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https).